# Moving an image randomaly inside a div

Tags: javascript, jquery

this is my code :

```
 <style type="text/css">
    #box
    {
        width: 400px;
        height: 400px;
        border: 1px solid;
        cursor: none;
    }
      #Parachute
    {
    width: 25px;
    height: 25px;
    cursor: none;
    position: absolute;
    }
   </style>
   <script type="text/javascript">
      $("#StartGame").click(function () {
            animateDiv();


        });

        function makeNewPosition() {

            // Get viewport dimensions (remove the dimension of the div)
            var h = $("#box").height() - 25;
            var w = $("#box").width() - 25;

            var nh = Math.floor(Math.random() * h);
            var nw = Math.floor(Math.random() * w);

            return [nh, nw];

        }

        function animateDiv() {
            var newq = makeNewPosition();
            $('#Parachute').animate({ top: newq[0], left: newq[1] }, function () {
                animateDiv();
            });

        };

    <script>
   <centre>
  <div id="box">
        <img id="Parachute" src="Parachute.gif" width="25px" height="25px" />
    </div>
     <centre>
   <input type="button" id="StartGame" value="Start Game" />
```

the image isn't moving what am i doing wrong ?

Comment: Can you fiddle it..??

Comment: If that's the actual order of your script and html, you're trying to attach a handler to `#StartGame` before it exists.

Answer (score 2):

You need to adjust your css...
The position of the image should be set to `absolute` as you are using left and top:

```
#Parachute
{
    width: 400px;
    height: 400px;
    border: 1px solid;
    cursor: none;
    position: absolute;
}
```

Without changing your css you could also change the js to:

```
$('#Parachute').animate({ 'margin-top': newq[0], 'margin-left': newq[1] }, function () {
    animateDiv();
});
```

in order to get the desired result.

Comment: please check my edit it's working but it's working weirdly the image is not moving inside the div notice that my div is inside a center tag

Comment: i couldn't upload the image i never used jsfiddle before sorry :s

Answer (score 1):

You need to set position of img as absolute:

```
#Parachute{position:absolute}
```

Or animate `margin-top`, `margin-left`

http://jsfiddle.net/KyNDm/